# Is there an established way to use configuration files for a deployed MATLAB application?

Tags: file, matlab, configuration-files, matlab-deployment

I am working with a MATLAB project, and would like to be able to configure variables and paths without re-creating the executable (currently done by using MATLAB's built-in deploytool).   I realize I can create a simple text file, listing key=value pairs, and read that in during run-time.  There doesn't seem to be any built-in support in MATLAB for creating configuration files that follow a standard format.

Are there any standard existing ways to use configuration files for MATLAB-generated executables?

Answer (score 2):

1) Add your resource to the package in DeployTool in the shared resources part
2) Read by using:

```
fullfile(ctfroot(),'config.txt');
```

**Edit** : That is suitable if your configuration is "private", that is the user should not edit it. In this case it is deployed together with your program as a resource. If you want a "public" config for the users, I know of no better way than to do what you offered.

Comment: Would the resource in step 1 be a plain text file with my list of key=value pairs?  Or something I would first generate using MATLAB?

Comment: @joanna, Probably a plain text file. But I would recommend XML or jason file format

Comment: I do want the user to be able to edit the configuration, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm going to remove the answer mark for now, in case anyone else can offer other ideas.